# Conditionally adding custom code in ANTLR grammar

Tags: antlr4, portability

I am writing a grammar that needs some custom code written in its target language. It is fairly easy to add e.g.

```
@parser::members {
}
```

The problem is that I am targeting multiple languages, and I haven't found a way to target multiple languages without copy+pasting the entire grammar.

Is there a way without resorting to copy+paste or external preprocessors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no solution. Action code is by definition written in the target language, as it is directly copied from the grammar to the generated files. If you have target languages that all can handle `#ifdef #endif` (say, C, C++ and Obj-C) then you could use that to separate individual code parts. Otherwise you could use a base grammar with placeholders and process that in a pre-compilation step (where you generate your parsers/lexers) and replace the placeholders with the real target code. That even makes the grammar cleaner.

Comment: That is more or less what I am designing now (I use a template engine to transform the grammar in a pre-processing step). I just thought there might be a more obvious way.

Comment: And I agree that separating target language from grammar makes the code easier to read. I would have preferred ANTLR to have something like it built-in though, or at least a documented best practice for dealing with it.